# Rounded UIScrollView Performance

Tags: iphone, performance, ios, uiscrollview, calayer

This runs great on iPhone 4 and 3GS:

```
scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 11;
scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

But on iPhone 3G and iPod touch 2nd gen, it makes scrolling really jerky. I know there are some tricks on how to improve performance of `CALayer` drop shadows for instance (setting `shouldRasterize` to YES and the `shadowPath` property), is there anything similar that can be done for CALayer's cornerRadius?

Comment: hmm.. my understanding is that cglayers are rendered on the GPU. Might be the source of your problems.

Comment: Are you suggesting any workaround? I'm well aware that older devices have much slower GPUs. Isn't there a way to obtain the same results but using the CPU?

Comment: I think the problem is that it _is_ using the CPU instead of GPU to render the rounded corners.  As far as I know, the only way to get snappy rounded corners on older devices is to avoid `cornerRadius` and instead do your clipped drawing in `drawRect:` or draw into a `UIImage`.

Comment: I'm curious, have you tried making the view opaque?

Comment: not sure if this is an option for you, but worth a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595267/uitableview-scrolling-performance-with-calayer-mask

Comment: Take a look at this at CocoaControls, it rounds an UITableView, and I think it could be useful to you > http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/roundeduitableview

Comment: @slf making the view opaque won't work with the round corners, since the background view is dynamic. That links suggests some kind of workaround by adding "fake" round corners on top of my tableview. Could definitely work, but since the bg image is dynamic I would have to generate those at runtime. Let's say I'd like this to be my last resort.

Comment: @zad0xsis that control uses the CALayer mask property as well; it's an exact replica of my described problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the content behind your scroll view (what’s being displayed under the rounded-off corners) a solid color or otherwise static? If so, you should be able to get way better performance by overlaying “corner” graphics—translucent at their center, and opaque (with your background color or whatever) at their edges—on top of the corners of your scroll view. The cost of compositing four 11x11 images over your content will be dramatically less than that of clipping it.

Comment: Like I said in the question's comments, my content behind the scroll view is not only an image but also dynamic. So I would have to generate the 4 round corner images at runtime every time the background image is changed. Isn't there a way to do it with CoreGraphics using CGContextClip()?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read all the comments. As far as I know, CALayers already use Core Graphics clipping to render their corners. You may well have to generate the four corner images at run-time, probably by using the superlayer's `-renderInContext:` method and then cutting pieces out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering of CALayers is way too slow for this use (especially on the older devices), it is not very good to use in games etc. You could switch to UIImages or cocos2d sprites, another option is to create your own layer class with OpenGL, although that one isnt quite as simple. Hope one of those options work for you.